# can someone explain what git rebase is doing in this picture?

Tags: git, github

[image: Rebase example]

From what I know about git rebase. It takes a topic branch and makes it point to the lastest commit in the master branch to get all the changes in the topic branch. However the branching in the picture is bothering me. First the topic branch gets merged with the server'smaster branch. which results in the `C6` commit. Then the person that merged the branch decides to rebase it. which should make the topic branch point to the latest commit in the master branch (excluding the merge commit. in this case, `C6`), ie `C4`. but instead what happens is `C4` is shifted to the lastest commit in the topic branch, ie `C5`. Shouldn't `C5` point to `C4` rather than the other way around. I've been trying to figure this out since morning lol.

Comment: It might actually be unhelpful to think about rebase using phrases like “topic branch”. The diagrams on that [page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) are showing the perils of rebasing. This section seems to be emphasising how confusing rebasing can be on a shared repo. The screenshot in this question isn’t really useful without the context of the others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling a little to follow your question and the diagrams, but this is how I usually think and teach others about how to think about `rebase`:
Say that your `master` looks like this: 1 <- 2 <- 3
And your topic branch is adding a new commit, 4: 1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4

Meanwhile, `master` gets a new commit, 5: 1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 5
Now the author wants to bring those changes into their topic branch, so they have two choices, `merge` or `rebase`. With a `merge` you would basically attach the new commits to the tip of the topic branch plus a merge commit, like: 1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4 <- 5 <- 5m
From there, the topic branch can be either merged again into master, but I personally find that this kind of history becomes confusing very fast. Something about the order of commits between branches changing when most of the time we consider `master` the "true" timeline.

So let's instead look at rebase. Rebase finds a common point between master and the topic branch (3), grabs the new commits from master (5) and applies it to the common point and then replays the new commits from the topic branch on to that: 1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 5 <- 4
This leaves you with a history that more resembles `master` so it's easier to see which commits your topic branch is adding, and this topic branch can also be merged into `master` using `fast-forward`.

Generally I tend to prefer to use a style that mixes both merge and rebase in my projects. When code is being worked on, in a topic branch/pull request, I use rebase to bring new changes in from `master`, keeping the history as a "add on". Then, when merging code into `master` I use `fast-forward` merge. When merging/promoting between long lived branches (say `integration` to `master`) I use `no fast forward` to get a merge commit that marks in the timeline when this promotion happened.

I very much agree with the comment saying that rebase on a long lived branch can be very dangerous and confusing, but rebasing a topic branch can help keep the history of the long lived branch cleaner since it'll allow you to use `fast forward`. The key difference is that your topic branch is usually not shared, so rewriting the history won't impact anyone but you, while rewriting the history of a shared branch can easily create conflicts.

Regarding your exact question, one thing you seem confused about is the effect a remote rebase change has on the local topic branch. The new rebased master in itself does not impact the topic branch at all. It is only when the author of the topic branch tries to integrate with the new changes that you run into issues. Because the rebase created new commits, you end up in a situation where the remote master has commits C4' but your local master has commits C4 and C5, these are not the same commits (same patch, different commits). But to integrate your topic branch with the remote master you need to make your histories compatible. This is what the diagram shows when it's adding the C8 commit (which is a simple merge commit) but the problem is that this history still has the C7 commit (made from merging C3 and C6 which no longer should exist in the remote master).
So you end up with a history that includes commits that have been removed from the remote history, but your history depends on them.

One way to work around this in the extreme case (prefer to not end up in this mess!) is to simply note down the commit hashes of your new commits (not the merge commits), reset your topic branch to the tip of the remote master, then cherry-pick your commits back into your topic branch so that they are re-applied on top of the new remote history. The article does mention using `rebase` again to solve this in an easier way but I have never used that approach so I cannot comment on it.